# Jersey href Relative Path in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, html, maven, tomcat, jersey

I am using:

1. IntelliJ 12
2. Java 7
3. Maven 3.0.5
4. Jersey 2.0
5. Tomcat 7

I am following some of the basic instructions at https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html under section 1.4 (JavaEE). Using maven to create the basic framework works great and importing into IntelliJ is super easy. I even have a basic test setup. The issue I run into is this. Building and deploying the war file works great and I can visit .../xyz-jersey-test/webapi/myresource] using IE or Firefox. My index.jsp has the following:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Jersey RESTful Web Application!</h2>
    <p><a href="webapi/myresource">Jersey resource</a>
    <p>Visit <a href="http://jersey.java.net">Project Jersey website</a>
    for more information on Jersey!
</body>
</html>
```

The ahref link in Tomcat doesn't have http:// and when I click on the link I get a 404. I can curl to .../xyz-jersey-test/webapi/myresource just fine but of course I have http://.

My question is this. When I click on the link how do I prefix that with http://? Is that done as a setting in Tomcat or in the .jsp or somewhere else? Everything else seems to work great except clicking on the link because of not having http:// (i.e. .../xyz-jersey-test/webapi/myresource). This is all at localhost:8080.

Comment: Wich link are you talking about? If you're talking about the href property of the a element, you DO NOT have to prefix anything with http://. If you're getting a 404 error, your link is problably really broken.

Comment: Woops. I am talking about the webapi/myresource link. I'll do some more research. Maybe I am not following the directions in the walk through correctly.

Comment: Notice that if a link is not preceeded by a / which means the website root, it is relative to the current address. Eg: if you're at the page www.example.com/page1 -> href="/" goes to the root www.example.com, href="webapi/myresource" goest to www.example.com/page1/weapi/myresource

Comment: That was it! The preceding '/' worked. Thank you!